# Moving Buttons on HTML

Tags: html, button, web

I'm trying to do a project where I put buttons of with the name of states over a state on a map and you click on the button to get the capital of the state. My code for the California button is:

< form action="http://www.cityofsacramento.org/" >

< input type="submit" value="California" / >

< /form >

but I have no idea how to move the button up to reach California:( it is currently in the bottom left corner of the screen.  I'm using Mozilla Thimble to make the website if that helps?

Comment: If you're making a website, CSS is a pretty important thing to learn.

Comment: You haven't shown the button element in the HTML you posted. Why not just put it right after the form? And are you sure you even need a form? Won't an anchor element (`<a>`) suffice?

Comment: I tried using <a> but it wouldn't bring me to the website.

Comment: `a` elements are links, their main purpose is showing the user to go to a different website. What did you write that didn't work? And did you try moving the button to immediately below the form?

Comment: if i use anything else besides form it doesn't work, i originally used <button>. I added this code:   <input type="submit" value="California" height=100px/> but it didn't do anything and that's when i got stuck

Comment: yeah adding it below form messed up

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to want to do is create a CSS file and designate an ID for each button:

```
<button type="button" id = "California"><a href="http://www.cityofsacramento.org/">Sacremento</a></button>
```

In your CSS file you can do something like this:

```
.California {
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    left-margin:[make it fit];
    right-margin:[make it fit];
    top-margin:[make it fit];
    bottom-margin:[make it fit];
}
```

you can then adjust the [make it fit] values to whatever dimensions land it on California. This is a very elementary fix - there are more advanced ways but I'm assuming you are new to web-development.